# Can Deep Learning be applied to Computational Fluid Dynamics

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Can Deep Learning be applied to Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) to develop turbulence models that are less computationally expensive compared to traditional CFD modeling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the paper [Deep learning in fluid dynamics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/deep-learning-in-fluid-dynamics/F2EDDAB89563DE5157FC4B8342AD9C70/core-reader) (by J. Nathan Kutz), and you will find your answer.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. This is exactly what I was looking for, especially the cited article by Ling et al (2016) - http://bit.ly/2UQlznV. The article seems to be a pivotal one applying Deep Neural Networks to a model Reynolds Averaged Navier-Stokes system.